# http GET and AngularJS UI Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am building my first Angular app with UI router and I need help on how to perform a http Get when a template loads. Thanks!

I've set up a plunker:
http://embed.plnkr.co/LRSGXqxjtbYcr6rjTj69/preview

I need to pass a userID to get the right info from the DB.

```
app.controller('SpecsController', function ($scope) {
  //I want to get this data with an AJAX call every time specs.html is loaded:
    $scope.specsList = [
    { title: 'ISBN', lastModified: '2014-12-12', usedIn: 2, id: '123' },
    { title: 'Brand', lastModified: '2013-11-10', usedIn: 5, id: '456' }
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to event **$stateChangeStart**

Check documentation here 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events

**Edited**

Something like this

```
app.controller('SpecsController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $http) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
    function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
      $http.get('url')
        .then(function(result) {
          $scope.specsList = result.data;
        });

    });
});
```

**UPDATE** 
ok, I understand the problem, you need to listen for $viewContentLoaded, check this plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/2hdjcUqd3cGAvn62jDxW?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. I am all new to this, so I would need a more specific example to be sure about what to do I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it. Something is not working. The items are not listed. I am using listSpecs.html for the data. Could you please take a quick look at my Plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/LRSGXqxjtbYcr6rjTj69/

Comment: I added plunker list, check it :)

Comment: Thanks! Really appreciate it. How do I pass a userId with the http get so I can get the right info from the DB. The UserId needs to be available "globally" in the app and would be loaded when the app starts.

Comment: Also, if the GET returns zero results (not an error, if the user hasn't created any items). How do I hide the table and instead show a text? "You haven't added any specifications."